# HTML Calculated Column Formula Help!

Tags: sharepoint, calculated-columns

I'm trying to use a HTML calculated column so that I can display a RAG status bar for my tasks in SharePoint. I had it working until I added the IF containing % complete. Can you tell me where I'm going wrong please?

Understand there is a < missing in front of the DIV Style in the first and last lines - only way I could get it to display:

```
<DIV style='width:100%;background-color:"&IF(Slippage>30,"red",IF(AND(Slippage>=-7,Slippage<=-29),"orange",IF(AND(Slippage>=-7,Slippage<=29),"orange",IF(Slippage<7,"green","green",IF(% Complete=100,"blue","blue")))))&";'></DIV>"
```

Thanks - Rob

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it! If you post error messages, **please** use the blockquotes ( ` " ` ) to properly format the error message.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably too late to be of use, but you should use square brackets around your column names; especially when there's a space in them.

As your troublesome `% Complete` column has a space in it, I imagine changing it to `[% Complete]` will resolve the issue. This means SharePoint will identify it as a single column name rather than two separate entities.